# How to save selected features from a postgis database into a new mini database

Tags: postgis, database, select-by-location

I have a postgis(v2.1.3)/postgresql(v9.3) database with geometry (geom1, geom2, etc.) and attribute (attr1, attr2, attr3, etc.) tables.  The attribute tables are linked to the geometry tables using foreign keys.  I use QGIS to view all these tables.  I want to select features in QGIS (either using a rectangle, polygone or manual select) from the map and then create a mini-database using only these selected features (from the geometry tables) and the relevant records from the attribute tables.  Is this possible?  Ideally I want the mini-database to be in spatialite/sqlite but I can find a way to convert from postgis to spatialite using ogr2ogr.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have two options:

1. Add all tables into QGIS, perform Joins on geom and non geom tables, select features in map and save selection as spatiallite DB

OR

2. Create a spatial view in POSTGIS, add view to QGIS, select features in map and save selection as spatiallite DB

Comment: Thanks for the 2 options, they work but at the cost of losing the structure of my database.  Also, I have multiple cases of cardinality 1:N, eg one geometry feature has multiple entries in the attr1, attr2, etc. tables).  Trying to recreate the structure of the database is going to be a pain!